# What does the question mark mean?

Tags: scala, kind-projector

I have following code functions:

```
  def jsonOrBadRequest[F[_] : Monad](service: HttpService[F])
  : HttpService[F]
  = {
    object dsl extends Http4sDsl[F]
    import dsl._
    Kleisli[OptionT[F, ?], Request[F], Response[F]] { req =>
      req.contentType match {
        case Some(s) =>
          if (s != `Content-Type`(MediaType.`application/json`))
            OptionT.liftF(BadRequest("Malformed format."))
          else
            service(req)
        case None =>
          OptionT.liftF(BadRequest("Malformed format."))
      }
    }
  }
```

and wanted to know, what does the question mark mean? It is from the library https://github.com/non/kind-projector.

Comment: `?` is a valid identifier just like `a`, `T`, and `theNumberOfPizzasInTheOven`. I imagine `kind-projector` defines `?` in some specific way, so check their documentation. It's not a special Scala syntax.

Comment: In which case should I use the question mark?

Answer (score 3):

This is not special Scala syntax. `?` is a valid identifier like anything else. `kind-projector` uses it to declare type-level lambdas. For example,

> ```
> Tuple2[?, Double]        // equivalent to: type R[A] = Tuple2[A, Double]
> Either[Int, +?]          // equivalent to: type R[+A] = Either[Int, A]
> Function2[-?, Long, +?]  // equivalent to: type R[-A, +B] = Function2[A, Long, B]
> EitherT[?[_], Int, ?]    // equivalent to: type R[F[_], B] = EitherT[F, Int, B]
> ```

(Examples taken directly from the [`kind-projector` documentation](https://github.com/non/kind-projector#inline-syntax))

Comment: Can you show me some use case for example `Either[Int, +?]`. Left is type `Int` and Right is type of?

Comment: In which case should I use the question instead of type variable.